# Emacs keys to move in pop ups of auto-complete

Tags: emacs, popup

I am setting my Emacs for cpp development.

I have set up auto-complete and yasnippets and it is great.

But every time one of pop up comes, i have to reach the mouse to click the lowest or middle one..

It must be possible with keys too but i struggled to find one.

I found this article [keys-for-pop-up](http://osdir.com/ml/emacs.jdee/2002-11/msg00130.html) but i think he is speaking about auto-completing without asking the user or showing no pops.

Comment: @abo-abo can you give me the source of that so that i do not have to ask questions like this.. ?

Comment: Just `C-s` auto-complete.el for `define-key`. But this shortcut I just remember.

Comment: I start reading Emacs tutorial and saw this key for previous and next line.. so cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone reading this, to move up or down in the auto-complete popup:

Move down: M-n

Move up: M-p

Here's the complete mode map from auto-complete.el

```
(define-key map "\t" 'ac-expand)
(define-key map [tab] 'ac-expand)
(define-key map "\r" 'ac-complete)
(define-key map [return] 'ac-complete)
(define-key map (kbd "M-TAB") 'auto-complete)

(define-key map "\M-n" 'ac-next)
(define-key map "\M-p" 'ac-previous)
(define-key map [down] 'ac-next)
(define-key map [up] 'ac-previous)

(define-key map [f1] 'ac-help)
(define-key map [M-f1] 'ac-persist-help)
(define-key map (kbd "C-?") 'ac-help)
(define-key map (kbd "C-M-?") 'ac-persist-help)

(define-key map [C-down] 'ac-quick-help-scroll-down)
(define-key map [C-up] 'ac-quick-help-scroll-up)
(define-key map "\C-\M-n" 'ac-quick-help-scroll-down)
(define-key map "\C-\M-p" 'ac-quick-help-scroll-up)
```